Possible CodeReviewThreadTypes of Azure Devops Git Api Threads
I was unable to find anywhere on the internet what the accepted CodeReviewThreadType values were in the Azure DevOps Thread API.
I am trying to make our remote service add a system message like "Pull Request successfully linked with XY." and don't want to spam it with huge comments.
I tried abusing some of the types that I usually see in pullrequests - StatusUpdate, RefUpdate, ReviewersUpdate, IsDraftUpdate... but they seem to be translated so the "content" of the comment is ignored and the message stays empty.
Does anyone have any experience with this? I don't need all supported types, just one that gives the desired output.
Desired output with example of content being ignored:

Code sample:
await gitApi.createThread({
    comments: [
        {
            parentCommentId: 0,
            content: "System Comment Test",
            commentType: CommentType.System,
        },
    ],
    properties: {
        CodeReviewThreadType: {
            "$type": "System.String",
            "$value": "StatusUpdate"
        },
    },
}, (pr.repository!).id!, pr.pullRequestId!);



I am trying to make our remote service add a system message like "Pull Request successfully linked with XY." and don't want to spam it with huge comments.

It seems that there is no API can create a system message in the pull request currently.
Maybe you can try the workaround to Comment on the pull request with the default status closed. This would reduce the time you manually close the comment.
sample script:
$organization = ""
$project=""
$pullRequestId="64"
$PAT=""

$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }
$Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$($project)/_apis/git/repositories/testrepo/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads?api-version=7.2-preview.1"

$body = @"
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "parentCommentId": 0,
      "content": "Pull Request successfully linked with XY."
    }
  ],
  "status": "closed"
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri  -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
$response | ConvertTo-Json


Result:

You can also request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better. Engineers usually prioritize features that are urgent or have more votes.

Thank you, I currently have the comments set up, but it was making it hard to see the actual code review. I also realized that the threads are rendered client-side, so I managed to find the code that renders it and just as I suspected, all of the types are using predefined translated messaged, none of them display the actual content.
In the end I chose to append the "Linked to XY" messages right into the pullrequest description, where it takes the least space and also allows me to add hyperlinks.

I've also created the azure devops feature request, as per you suggestion. Thank you.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-CodeReviewThreadType-for-PullRequ/10684518
